# trying to update empty string field with a string

Tags: arcpy, cursor, update, string

I need to update a column of values such that empty fields are changed to the string "OFF_ROAD."  I've looked up a plethora of examples, and this is what I'm trying to get to work, but when I run it, nothing happens to the input file-

```
import arcpy

from arcpy import env

env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.env.workspace = "F:/EMILY/TEST/GET_TYPE_TEST/"

infc = "SpJoinscript.shp"

cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(infc) 

for row in cur:

if row.TYPE_1 == "":         
    row.TYPE_1 = "OFF_ROAD"      
cur.updateRow(row) 
del row

del cur

print "done mothaf"
```

what am I overlooking here???!!!

Answer (score 1):

If the field is empty (or NULL), the thing to test is whether the field is `None`.

Try changing the `if row.TYPE_1 == "":` to `if row.TYPE_1 is None:`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out- I used a da.updateCursor with an SQL query-
    import arcpy

```
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.env.workspace = "F:/EMILY/TEST/GET_TYPE_TEST/"


infc = "SpJoinscript.shp"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(infc, "TYPE_1", "TYPE_1=''") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = "OFF_ROAD"
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```